# Никак не могу заставить переименовываться имя на даблклик в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У нас есть список гостей, он работает и тут все хорошо:

```
class GuestList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        list: [],
        guest: '',
        twoguests: false,
        key: uuidv4(),
        count: 0,
        editing: true,
    };
};

createNewGuest = () => {
    this.setState(({list, guest, twoguests, key, count}) => ({
        list: [
            ...list,
            {
                guest,
                key,
                twoguests,
            }
        ],
        twoguests: false,
        guest: '',
        key: uuidv4(),
        count: this.state.twoguests ? count + 2 : count + 1,
    }));
};

handleInput = e => {
    this.setState({
        guest: e.target.value
    });
};

handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== '') {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.createNewGuest();
        }
    }
};

handleCheckBox = () =>
    this.setState({
        twoguests: !this.state.twoguests
    });

excludeGuest = keyToDelete => {
        this.setState(({ list }) => ({
            list: list.filter((GuestList, key) => key !== keyToDelete),
        }));
    };

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            <div className = "guest_list">
                {this.state.list.map((person, key) =>
                    <div>
                    <Guest
                    name = {person.guest}
                    onChange={this.handleInput}
                    two_people = {person.twoguests ? ' --- Придет с парой' : ' --- Придет один'}
                    key = {person.key}
                    excludeGuest = {this.excludeGuest.bind(this,key)}
                    />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
            <div className="creating_new_guest">
                <input
                  placeholder="Имя гостя"
                  value={ this.state.guest }
                  onChange={this.handleInput}
                  onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}>
                </input>
                <button>
                    Записать нового гостя
                </button>
            </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            onClick={this.handleCheckBox}
                            checked={this.twoguests}
                        >
                        </input>
                        Придёт с парой
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                Всего гостей будет: {this.state.count}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Также имеется собственно сам компонент гостя, который при даблклике меняет див на инпут

```
class Guest extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editing: true,
        name: 'TEST',
    }
}

startEdit = () => this.setState ({
    editing: !this.state.editing
});

handleRename = e => {
    this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    });
};
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div>
                {this.state.editing ?
                <div
                    onDoubleClick={this.startEdit}>
                    {this.props.name}
                </div>
                :
                <input
                    value = {this.props.name}
                    onDoubleClick={this.startEdit}
                    onChange={this.handleRename}>
                </input>}

                <div className = 'quanitity'>
                {this.props.two_people}
            </div>
                <div>
                    <button /*Исключаем гсстя по необходимости*/
                        onClick = {this.props.excludeGuest}>
                        Убрать
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Guest
```

Собственно никак не могу заставить при двойном нажатии на созданном элементе превратить его в инпут(это сделано) а потом редактировать его, так. что при новом даблклике новая информация сохранится

Comment: Пытаюсь играться с пропсами и стейтом, смог вынести такой компонент отдельно, но он ни с чем не связан, просто текст, меняющийся на ипут и редактирующийся внутри него. как его вставить вместо создаваемого имени в список - хз

Comment: помоему Вы выводите name из props-ов, а записываете в state

Comment: Я их туда-сюда кидаю, я понять не могу, как связать стейтовые имена между компонентами. Пропсы же и неужны для связи

Comment: для связи данных между компонентами лучше использовать redux - оно как раз для этого.

Comment: Да это то понятно, но тут же буквально пары строк убавить/добавить не хватает, тобы такая мелочь заработала

Comment: в родительском компоненте (из которого вы передаете name) сделайте функцию которая будет менять имя - и передавайте саму функцию как prop  в дочерний компонент - и уже в дочернем компоненте вызывайте именно эту функцию... как то так)